# Setting a shift-like key for changing language layout in KDE

Tags: kde, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Is there a way to set a shift-like (not tab-like) hot-key for changing language layout in a KDE environment so that the language layout toggles again when the key is pressed and toggles to the original state when the key is released?

Comment: I was thinking it is possibe to grab a key and listening to it with an X11 program when it is pressed or released. But there may be a better simpler method.

Answer (score 1):

Settings manager >> keyboard >> shortcuts tab, click add, enter the command: $ setxkbmap -layout (languageKey) this will switch to one language only but you can set a key for each language or you could create your own file to toggle when the key binding is pressed